# Gremlin DSE Graph Error: schema.getClass()

Tags: datastax, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

Using the Datastax Sandbox 5.0 in Virtual Box. Transcript below... the command from the tutorial doesn't work. I used a ":remote" command from TP3 documentation since I couldn't find what to use for DSE Graph. It worked, but not sure my steps are correct.

> gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
>   ==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182 gremlin> system.describe()
>   ==>system.graph("STUDIO_TUTORIAL_GRAPH").create() system.graph("KillrVideo").create() gremlin> schema.getClass() No such
>   property: schema for class: Script1 Display stack trace? [yN] 
>   gremlin>

Answer (score 1):

When you issue this command:

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
```

you create a "remote". That part is fine, however you then need to send your requests to DSE Graph via `:submit` or it's more commonly used alias `:>`:

```
gremlin> :> schema.getClass()
```

Alternatively, you can put the "remote" in *[console mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#console-remote-console)* by doing:

```
:remote console
```

at which point you can then issue your command as:

```
gremlin> schema.getClass()
```

The Gremlin Console packaged with DSE should do this for you automatically at startup. It should configure the remote and set it up for console mode out of the box. It's odd that this is not happening for you.